# gnuplot plot difference of 2 columns

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have two files A and B. Both files contain 2 columns, x and y.

Now, I want to plot a graph for x vs (yA - yB). Does gnuplot provide a command for the same ?

One more thing, lets say xA and xB are not same. How should I plot a graph where x-axis contains all elements which are in both, xA and xB and y-axis is the difference is the corresponding y-components ?

Comment: Are the xA and xB items always *exactly* matching, down to the characters? Or could 5.0000 be merged with 5.0001?

Comment: they are exactly same. the column of merge is an unsigned integer.

Comment: "all the elements which are in both" -- This (to me) is ambiguous.  Do you want the union or the intersection?  It sounds like you want the intersection but in case you wanted the union I provided a solution for that below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, preprocess the files with `join` in bash:

```
join <(sort -k1,1 file1) <(sort -k1,1 file2) > file3
```

Sorting the files is essential, otherwise `join` would not work.

Then you can use the result to draw the graph:

```
plot '< sort -n file3' using 1:($2-$3) with lines
```

Again, numeric sorting is needed here, because `join` uses alphanumeric sorting which makes the lines cross each other.

Comment: *If* this turns out to be slow (3 sorts) for large data, a perl/Python script might be a better bet. Also, couldn't the first two sorts be numeric, and thereby avoid the third sort?

Comment: @PhilH: Unfortunately, `join` needs alphanumeric sorting (as already mentioned). Try it to see. If there is any complication, I'd also reach for a more advanced language (Perl in my case).

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be a good job for `paste`.

```
plot "<paste A B" u 1:($2-$4) w points #whatever line style you want...
                  #xA #yA-yB
```

For the file where xA != xB, I'm a little unclear whether you want to plot only the set of points with are common to both (the intersection of the two sets) or whether you want to plot all the points (the union of the sets).  The union is easy:

```
plot "<paste A B" u 1:($2-$4) w points ls 1,\
     "<paste A B" u 3:($2-$4) w points ls 1
```

The intersection is hard using only unix commandline tools (especially if you want to preserve the order of your input)

using Python though, it's not too bad...

```
#joinfiles.py
import sys
f1=sys.argv[1]
f2=sys.argv[2]
xA,yA=zip(*[map(float,line.split()) for line in f1.readlines()])
xB,yB=zip(*[map(float,line.split()) for line in f2.readlines()])
f1.close()
f2.close()
for i,x in enumerate(xA):
    if(x in xB):
        sys.stdout.write('%f %f %f\n'%(x,yA[i],yB[i]))
```

and then from gnuplot:

```
plot "<python joinfiles.py A B" u 1:($2-$3) #...
```