# Gnuplot: Subtracting two plots with different y and x values

Tags: gnuplot, interpolation, difference, subtraction

I have two different data sets A and B. I'd like to subtract the y-values of A and B, meaning

`plot 'data.dat' u 1:($2-$4)`.

The problem is that A and B do not share the same x-values, like:

```
0   0   0   0
1   2   0.5 1.5
2   4   1.0 3.0
3   6   1.5 4.5
```

The range is the same, but the density of x-values in A is higher than in B

How can I fix this? An idea is interpolation, but how?

application context: difference spectroscopy

Comment: This question was already posted, but not answered: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10698586/2799037